# Action Listeners in Action Listeners Error

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So, I have a JFrame by the name of rename inside of a JButton ActionListener. The following text below is

```
JFrame rename = new JFrame("Rename File");

//other code
JButton renameb = new JButton();

renameb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Console.file = namef.getText();
            dispose();


        }
    });
```

and whenever I run this, it just shows this:

http://sp.itbind.com/s/misha/Screen%20Shot%202016-11-17%20at%2011.05.27%20PM.png
( I had to put a link because copy-paste doesn't work)

Comment: Is there any error/warning in Console?

Comment: @Jobin   no, it just appears like that. I have no idea why

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: @Jobin sure: http://sp.itbind.com/s/misha/text1.txt

Comment: You don't need to know about the array as list thing and the error class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `String filen = file + ".txt";` to `String filen = file.getText() + ".txt";`

Now the root cause of `Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is you are missing the following line

`rename.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`   after 
`JFrame rename = new JFrame("Rename File");`

Note: To use `GridBagConstraints`  you need to set `Layout` as `GridBagLayout`

Comment: I am not sure this will fix your issue.. but this need to be fixed.. please try it and let me know

Comment: Actually, the jtextfield file is never announced because im changing the layout, so it isn't supposed to be like that. This did resolve the random text, but calling the action listener now brings up :    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)

Comment: Okay can you post the stack trace?